# Saving data with a file name of my choice

Tags: vb.net, listview

Very kindly, an intelligent member of stack overflow showed me how to loop with 'Do Until' and generate messages boxes to enable a user to save a file or rename one, if it already exists.  However, I'm still hitting a wall.  I can't save the ListView data in my for loop, with the file name I have chosen in the Input Box (see code below). Its like I have two separate pieces of code because rtb is saving data in a Rich Text File called Test.txt and saveFile has nothing to do with this! Please help

Code

```
 Dim fileSaved As Boolean

    Do Until fileSaved
        Dim saveFile As String = InputBox("Enter a file name to save this message")
        If saveFile = "" Then Exit Sub
        Dim docs As String = My.Computer.FileSystem.SpecialDirectories.MyDocuments
        Dim filePath As String = IO.Path.Combine(docs, "Visual Studio 2013\Projects", saveFile & ".txt")

            fileSaved = True
            If My.Computer.FileSystem.FileExists(filePath) Then
                Dim msg As String = "File Already Exists. Do You Wish To Overwrite it?"
                Dim style As MsgBoxStyle = MsgBoxStyle.YesNo Or MsgBoxStyle.DefaultButton2 Or MsgBoxStyle.Critical
                fileSaved = (MsgBox(msg, style, "Warning") = MsgBoxResult.Yes)
            End If
        Loop

        'THIS NEXT bit of code saves content to Test.txt NOT saveFile as desired!

        Dim rtb As New RichTextBox
        rtb.AppendText("Generation, Num Of Juveniles, Num of Adults, Num of Semiles, Total" & vbNewLine)
        For Each saveitem As ListViewItem In ListView1.Items
            rtb.AppendText(
                           saveitem.Text & ", " &
                           saveitem.SubItems(1).Text & ", " &
                           saveitem.SubItems(2).Text & ", " &
                           saveitem.SubItems(3).Text & ", " &
                           saveitem.SubItems(4).Text & vbNewLine)
        Next
        rtb.SaveFile("C:\Users\SMITH\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\Test.txt", _
        RichTextBoxStreamType.PlainText)
```

Comment: Instead of an InputBox, a `FileSaveDialog` will provide navigation and validation to the selection and optionally the `overwrite?` question.

Comment: if you dont want the LV text in `test.txt` dont put it in the RTB, write it to the file.

Comment: I don't think that the SO member you are referring was expecting you to not even understand the main parts of the code. You should take Steve's correction as an excuse to re-read this whole code and understand it completely. Why were you expecting the file to be stored somewhere else by having the path hardcoded ("rtb.SaveFile("C:\Users\SMITH\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\Test.txt"").

Comment: @varocarbas Understood. But I could not eliminate the hardcode.  I had two systems that worked - but not together. I spent some time trying to merge the two, but got no closer.

Comment: You are still using the hard coded filename in your call to `SaveFile`. I suggested that you use `filePath` instead.

Comment: No, I think that you didn't understand. You are asking the user about the desired file name, the user types "test", for example, you store "mydocuments\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\test.txt" in the variable filePath. You check that this path is OK (or ask for replacing the existing file)... and then when you have to just save this path, the one stored in filePath, you write the following: rtb.SaveFile("C:\Users\SMITH\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\Test.txt", _
        RichTextBoxStreamType.PlainText). So... where is the information finally stored? Steve has solved it for you.

Comment: @varocarbas Its stored in the terminal statement. I tried to graft one solution onto a very eloquent block of code but it was because I did not understand how to combine the two. I was hoping someone would explain why the two would never join. I understand that it can be frustrating trying to help someone learning the basics. My apologies

Comment: @Blackwood. I hope you don't feel I under appreciated your solution. I read up about message boxes to really get to grips with what you said, by  Bryan Newsome - it really helped. Unfortunately, he only talks about FileSaveDialog so couldn't get to grips with file path

Comment: Follow the instructions given by Steve step by step. You would see that your code needs two modifications: one is changing the location of Dim filePath As String and the other is writing rtb.SaveFile(filePath... rather than rtb.SaveFile("C:\Users\SMITH\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\Test.txt",... Implement it, confirm that it works; then compare the new parts vs. the old ones and wonder about the reason for these changes or ask. But why do you keep saying abstract things with no real meaning? It is not difficult, it is very easy; but make an effort to understand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you try to save the file with the RichTextBox method SaveFile you need to be able to use the variable `filePath` that receive the input from your user. But this variable is declared inside the block Do Until .... Loop and according to [scope rules of variables in VB.NET](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1t0wsc67.aspx) is not available outside that block. You could move the declaration of the variable before entering the loop

```
Dim fileSaved As Boolean

Dim filePath As String 
Do Until fileSaved
    Dim saveFile As String = InputBox("Enter a file name to save this message")
    If saveFile = "" Then Exit Sub
    Dim docs as String = My.Computer.FileSystem.SpecialDirectories.MyDocuments
    filePath = IO.Path.Combine(docs, "Visual Studio 2013\Projects", saveFile & ".txt")

    fileSaved = True
    If My.Computer.FileSystem.FileExists(filePath) Then
        Dim msg As String = "File Already Exists. Do You Wish To Overwrite it?"
        Dim style As MsgBoxStyle = MsgBoxStyle.YesNo Or MsgBoxStyle.DefaultButton2 Or MsgBoxStyle.Critical
        fileSaved = (MsgBox(msg, style, "Warning") = MsgBoxResult.Yes)
    End If
Loop

' The remainder of your code can be left unchanged until the SaveFile line
```

Now you could use it in the call

```
 rtb.SaveFile(filePath, RichTextBoxStreamType.PlainText)
```

Comment: Many thanks. I'm so sorry to sound so dense but when I tried to use the filePath as some sort of parameter, I kept getting syntax errors. Exactly how do I make the call?

Comment: @student in the code you posted, change the last statement to `rtb.SaveFile(filePath, RichTextBoxStreamType.PlainText)`.

Comment: @Blackwood thank you. I tried this suggestions but it comes up with filePath is not declared. If I declare it with Dim filePath at the top of the code as Steve suggests, it generates another error - 'Variable filePath hides a variable in an enclosing block'

Comment: @Student did you remove the Dim in front of the variable _filePath_ INSIDE the do until block? (And _As String_ also of course)

Comment: @Student, really you need to understand this point. It is like the angular stone of any programming language. I have offered a link above to help you but if you find it too theoric I suggest you to search about examples of variable scope in VB.NET.

Comment: A massive thanks to all those who helped. Blackwood, Steve - I'm so grateful - I love coding but its so flipping hard at times I will do some more reading online to fully get to grips with file saving but at least now I have a solid example to learn from. Thanx

Comment: @Steve Yes, I remember reading about Public and Private, Global and local. I think I need to invest some time in going back over that literature